# Preserve original type `tibble` in nested columns

Tags: r, nested, tidyr, tibble

I really like the new `tidyr` interface that came with `v1.0.0`.

However, with the tidyverse more or less being centered around `tibble`, I was a bit puzzled that the nested column seems to be a list of `data.frame`s - even when the original data was a `tibble` to begin with (in which case I would have expected that I end up with a list of `tibble`s in the nested column):

```
library(magrittr)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~x, ~y,
  1, 10, 20,
  1, 100, 200,
  2, 1, 2
)
df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      id     x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1    10    20
#> 2     1   100   200
#> 3     2     1     2

df %>% tidyr::nest_legacy(-id)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      id data            
#>   <dbl> <list>          
#> 1     1 <tibble [2 x 2]>
#> 2     2 <tibble [1 x 2]>

df %>% tidyr::nest(data = -id)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      id           data
#>   <dbl> <list<df[,2]>>
#> 1     1        [2 x 2]
#> 2     2        [1 x 2]
```

Is there any way the get to exact same result that `tidyr::nest_legacy()` gave/gives me?

Comment: I think `df %>% group_nest(id)` is giving you the desired results.

Comment: @tmfmnk thanks for the pointer. Still feels a bit confusing/inconsistent, though, as `group_nest()` lives in `dplyr` instead of `tidyr` and there's also `df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
  tidyr::nest()` which again gives me a list of `data.frame`s :-/

Comment: This might give the same result: `df %>% nest(data = -id) %>% mutate_at(vars(data), ~as.list(.))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the difference is the class of the data column when using `nest` versus `nest_legacy`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble::tribble(
   ~id, ~x, ~y,
   1, 10, 20,
   1, 100, 200,
   2, 1, 2
 )
 df
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#     id     x     y
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    10    20
#2     1   100   200
#3     2     1     2
```

Using both methods and checking if they are `tibble`s

```
 test1 <- df %>% nest(data = -id)
 test2 <- df %>% nest_legacy(-id)

 test1 %>% '[['(2) %>% '[['(1) %>% is_tibble()
[1] TRUE

 test1
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     id           data
#  <dbl> <list<df[,2]>>
#1     1        [2 x 2]
#2     2        [1 x 2]

 test2 %>% '[['(2) %>% '[['(1) %>% is_tibble()
[1] TRUE

 test2
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     id data            
#  <dbl> <list>          
#1     1 <tibble [2 x 2]>
#2     2 <tibble [1 x 2]>
```

Checking the class of the data column

```
 class(test1[[2]])
[1] "vctrs_list_of" "vctrs_vctr"   
 class(test2[[2]])
[1] "list"
```

Using `as.list` on your data column will produce the same results as `nest_legacy`

```
 test3 <- df %>% nest(data = -id) %>% mutate_at(vars(data), ~as.list(.))
 test3

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     id data            
#  <dbl> <list>          
#1     1 <tibble [2 x 2]>
#2     2 <tibble [1 x 2]>


 identical(test2, test3)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Great, thanks! But I don't really get why it works, how does `as.list()` suddenly turn a `data.frame` into a `tibble`?

Comment: @Rappster I think they are already `tibble`s, as in my answer if you look at `df %>% nest(-id) %>% '[['(2) %>% '[['(1) %>% is_tibble()` it will return `TRUE`. `as.list` is just changing the class of the `data` column to match what `nest_legacy` does.

Comment: Ah okay, got it. Seems like `tidyr` makes greater use of `vctrs`. Also a fan of `vctrs`, but I still find it confusing to now see `<list<df[,2]>>` and no info about `tibble`