# Different behavior of tidyr::nest on different systems and package / R versions

Tags: r, tidyr

Recently I have updated to `tidyr` version 1.0.0 on two different machines (PC and mac) running slightly different R and package versions.

The print output of `tiydr::nest` now shows slight differences. My question seems related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58505582/preserve-original-type-tibble-in-nested-columns/58507866#58507866), but is not. I am not interested in how to create identical results between the new `nest` and `nest_legacy` (this difference is what the post above is about). I am rather interested in why different print outputs occur, although the same `tidyr` version is used, and how I can fix this (the print output of my PC doesn't look correct).

Here is the output on my mac:

```
library(tidyr)

nested_tbl_mac <- iris %>%
  tidyr::nest(data = c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) 

nested_tbl_mac
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Species              data
#>   <fct>      <list<df[,4]>>
#> 1 setosa           [50 × 4]
#> 2 versicolor       [50 × 4]
#> 3 virginica        [50 × 4]

nested_tbl_mac[[2]] %>% class 
#> [1] "vctrs_list_of" "vctrs_vctr"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Here is the output from my pc:

```
library(tidyr)

nested_tbl_pc <- iris %>% 
  tidyr::nest(data = c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width))

nested_tbl_pc
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Species    data                                                          
#>   <fct>      <S3: vctrs_list_of>                                           
#> 1 setosa     5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.0, 5.4, 4.6, 5.0, 4.4, 4.9, 5.4, 4.8, 4~
#> 2 versicolor 7.0, 6.4, 6.9, 5.5, 6.5, 5.7, 6.3, 4.9, 6.6, 5.2, 5.0, 5.9, 6~
#> 3 virginica  6.3, 5.8, 7.1, 6.3, 6.5, 7.6, 4.9, 7.3, 6.7, 7.2, 6.5, 6.4, 6~

nested_tbl_pc[[2]] %>% class
#> [1] "vctrs_list_of" "vctrs_vctr"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

It seems like a printing issue to me. However, unlike in this [post here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/i-dont-understanding-nesting-anymore-in-tidyr/41495) I haven’t tweaked my printing options on neither of my machines.

The only packages I have loaded are `tidyr` and all base packages.

```
(.packages())
#> [1] "stats"     "graphics"  "grDevices" "utils"     "datasets"  "methods"  
#> [7] "base"
```

Finally, here a comparison between the versions of `tidyr` and all packages imported by `tidyr` on both of my machines (last row shows the R version):

```
#>    package    version_pc version_mac
#>    <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      
#>  1 tidyr      1.0.0      1.0.0      
#>  2 dplyr      0.8.3      0.8.3      
#>  3 ellipsis   0.3.0      0.2.0.1    
#>  4 glue       1.3.0      1.3.1      
#>  5 magrittr   1.5        1.5        
#>  6 purrr      0.3.2      0.3.3      
#>  7 Rcpp       1.0.2      1.0.2      
#>  8 rlang      0.4.1      0.4.0      
#>  9 stringi    1.2.4      1.2.2      
#> 10 tibble     2.1.1      2.1.3      
#> 11 tidyselect 0.2.5      0.2.5      
#> 12 utils      3.5.1      3.5.0      
#> 13 vctrs      0.2.0      0.2.0      
#> 14 lifecycle  0.1.0      0.1.0      
#> 15 R.Version  3.5.1      3.5.0
```

**Update**: I have now updated all packages imported by `tidyr` on my PC which had smaller version numbers than my mac (`glue`, `purrr` and `tibble`) and this does not solve the problem. I would like to refrain from downgrading to lower versions on my PC for `ellipsis`, `rlang`, `stringi` and `utils`.

**Solution**: As Matt hinted at in his answer, the cause of the problem was rooted in the `pillar` package. Updating from version `1.2.1` to `1.4.2` solved the printing issue. I approached the problem as a `tidyr` issue, but it actually was an issue of how (nested) tibbles get printed. Therefore, I should have looked at the dependencies of the `tibble` package as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% on this, but I think this is due to the printing options of `pillar`, and according to [this](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2018/04/pillar-1-2-2/) you can override the printing which may produce what you're looking for:

```
print.tbl_df <- function(x, ...) {
  print.data.frame(x, ...)
  invisible(x)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Updating the `pillar` package did the trick. I wasn't aware of it, since I only looked into the dependencies of `tidyr`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same result as the `mac`-version on my PC/windows machine. 
This doesn't seem like a serious issue to me.

Note that you're not using the latest version of R. This could be it.

```r
library(tidyr)

nested_tbl_mac <- iris %>%
  tidyr::nest(data = c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) 

nested_tbl_mac
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Species              data
#>   <fct>      <list<df[,4]>>
#> 1 setosa           [50 x 4]
#> 2 versicolor       [50 x 4]
#> 3 virginica        [50 x 4]
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64              
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32             
#>  ui       RTerm                       
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  English_United States.1252  
#>  ctype    English_United States.1252  
#>  tz       Europe/Paris                
#>  date     2019-11-25                  
#> 
#> - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package     * version    date       lib source                         
#>  assertthat    0.2.1      2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  backports     1.1.5      2019-10-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  callr         3.3.2      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  cli           1.1.0      2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  crayon        1.3.4      2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  desc          1.2.0      2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  devtools      2.2.1      2019-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  digest        0.6.23     2019-11-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  dplyr         0.8.3      2019-07-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  ellipsis      0.3.0      2019-09-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  evaluate      0.14       2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  fansi         0.4.0      2018-10-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  fs            1.3.1      2019-05-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  glue          1.3.1      2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  highr         0.8        2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  htmltools     0.4.0      2019-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  knitr         1.26       2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  lifecycle     0.1.0      2019-08-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  magrittr      1.5        2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  memoise       1.1.0.9000 2019-07-08 [1] Github (hadley/memoise@1650ad7)
#>  pillar        1.4.2      2019-06-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  pkgbuild      1.0.6      2019-10-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  pkgconfig     2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  pkgload       1.0.2      2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  prettyunits   1.0.2      2015-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  processx      3.4.1      2019-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  ps            1.3.0      2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  purrr         0.3.3      2019-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  R6            2.4.1      2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  Rcpp          1.0.3      2019-11-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  remotes       2.1.0      2019-06-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  rlang         0.4.2      2019-11-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  rmarkdown     1.17       2019-11-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  rprojroot     1.3-2      2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1      2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  stringi       1.4.3      2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  stringr       1.4.0      2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  testthat      2.3.0      2019-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  tibble        2.1.3      2019-06-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  tidyr       * 1.0.0      2019-09-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  tidyselect    0.2.5      2018-10-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  usethis       1.5.1.9000 2019-10-24 [1] Github (r-lib/usethis@b1fca08) 
#>  utf8          1.1.4      2018-05-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  vctrs         0.2.0      2019-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  withr         2.1.2      2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  xfun          0.11       2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                 
#>  yaml          2.2.0      2018-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#>  zeallot       0.1.0      2018-01-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                 
#> 
#> [1] C:/Users/[redacted]/Documents/R/win-library/3.6
#> [2] C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.1/library
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your output. My PC is my work computer so it will update to the latest R version long after it has been released. The R version of my mac is even older and here the problem doesn't occur. I really wonder whats causing this.